# Aquamacs hangs when refreshing package contents

Tags: init-file, use-package, error, aquamacs

I'm trying to use `use-package` in my `Preferences.el` file under Aquamacs 3.6.  Every time I try to run Aquamacs with the following `Preferences.el`, Aquamacs hangs, usually indefinitely.

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents) ;; Does not hang if this line is commented out
)
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?  Incidentally, if I comment out the `(package-refresh-contents)` line, then Aquamacs starts correctly.  Ultimately, I want to install `use-package` and use it within the remainder of my `Preferences.el`.

Comment: Which part of your init file causes it to hang? If you don’t know, try commenting out top–level expressions until the hang goes away.

Comment: @db48x It appears to be `(package-refresh-contents)` that causes the hang.  I've revised the code above.

Comment: For how long does it hang? Maybe it is just downloading a large list of packages. strace it and find out what it is doing while it is hung.

Comment: @db48x Thanks for your help!  I used `open -n /Applications/Aquamacs.app --args --debug-init`, which allowed me to see that Aquamacs was prompting me to decide whether to ignore expired certificates from melpa and gnu.  After ignoring, Aquamacs now boots promptly.

Comment: Nice. You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that the cause of Aquamacs hanging was that it was waiting for an answer to a prompt about ignoring expired certificates from melpa and gnu.
To discover this, I used

```
open -n /Applications/Aquamacs.app --args --debug-init
```

After choosing to ignore, Aquamacs now boots promptly.

Comment: Please report this as a bug to the Aquamacs folks. https://github.com/aquamacs-emacs/aquamacs-emacs/issues/new, it may be related to [#147](https://github.com/aquamacs-emacs/aquamacs-emacs/issues/147)